# seedstudio reterminal not turning off after sudo reboot

Tags: raspbian, linux, raspberry-pi-os

I am using the seedstudio reterminal with cm4 to make a program that involves sht20 sensor. I encountered an error and found one solution in editing the “boot/config.txt” , by just adding some lines that involves gpio. When I clicked the sudo reboot, the screen of the device will not turn on. The PWR and SYS Leds are on (yellow light) but the screen does not display anything.